MUI Datagrid: Row grouping with details showing in same cell
I am using datagrid mui row grouping. Here is the code.
const Report = () => {
  const apiRef = useGridApiRef();
  const initialState = useKeepGroupedColumnsHidden({
    apiRef,
    initialState: {
      sorting: {
        sortModel: [{ field: "__row_group_by_columns_group__", sort: "asc" }],
      },
      rowGrouping: {
        model: ["company", "vendorName"],
      },
    },
  });
  return (
        <DataGridPremium
          rows={[
            {
              id: 1,
              company: "Apple Inc.",
              vendorName: "Apple",
              unitId: "a1fsfsdfefsefsf",
              date: dayjs().format("MM/DD/YYYY"),
              lastGeneratedDate: dayjs().format("MM/DD/YYYY"),
            },
          ]}
          columns={[
            ...reportTableColumn,
            {
              field: "date",
              align: "left",
              headerName: "Date",
              headerAlign: "left",
              flex: 2,
            },
          ]}
          apiRef={apiRef}
          initialState={initialState}
        />
  );
};

Now what I want is to show the common details on the grouping row itselft. Have a look at the image the lastGeneratedDate should come above.


can you explain more : The Date should be visible on the root row as well as where it is presently or just on the root row?

@discovrer I want to show common fields in the same grouping row. Here unitId is different and apart from that other fields are common.
